# Do transaction in Django make things faster

Tags: django, database, transactions

I have a Django application.

This Django application makes an api call to Twitter and gets my 100 recent tweets. I need to insert the tweets into the database.

I have a method to act on all 100 tweets. This method has a for loop where I create a model instance out of each Tweet and call instance.save() on each instance separately.

I found things slower and thought that transactions might make things faster.

So outside the method I added `@method_decorator(transaction.atomic)`. I still have a for loop where I created model instance and do instance.save() but now the method is decorated with transaction.atomic.

1. Is transaction.atomic supposed to make insertions to database faster for me?
2. Will each instance.save() call still issue a database call?
3. If it makes things faster, then how?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**In an atomic transaction, a series of database operations either *all* occur, or *nothing* occurs.**

Decorating a method as `atomic` will guarantee atomicity on the database for the block of code within that method. If the method is successfully completed, the changes are committed to the database. If there is an exception, the changes are rolled back.

**1. Transactions will not make your code any faster as per your use case.** Infact, it will just guarantee that either all the `tweets` will be saved to the database or none of the `tweets` will be saved in the  case of an exception.

**2. Yes, each `instance.save()` call will be a database call.** So, there  would be 100 database calls each time.

**3. Again, Transactions won't make this any faster for your use case.**

**How to make things faster then?**

You can use Django's [`bulk_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) to create all the `tweets` in a single query.

```
Tweet.objects.bulk_create([tweet1, tweet2, ...., tweet100]) # single query
```

This inserts the list of `tweet` objects into the database in an efficient manner in only 1 query.

Comment: "Transactions will not make your code any faster." -- In practice this is often not true. Simply put, opening and closing a single transaction is way less work than opening and closing 100 transactions. Depending on your backend and storage engine, this may involve disk I/O, and it _can_ be a major bottleneck. `bulk_create()` is still your first choice to increase performance, and will be plenty for 100 items at a time, but don't just disregard transactions as a means to speed up your code. (And measure it, always measure it.)

Comment: Yeah agree with you on that part. Slightly modified the ans to not generalize it. And yes, measuring the time in both the cases would give would give a better picture.

Comment: Note that new django versions >2 also support bulk_update. Which was not possible before, and ofthen lead to calling save() for every object.

Answer (score 2):

1. No. The purpose of database transactions is to ensure data integrity. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction) for more information.
2. Yes. Using transactions won't affect this.
3. It doesn't.

What *should* make your code faster is submitting your new records all at once, in a single query, rather than one at a time. Look into Django's [`bulk_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create). It's always hard to predict performance, but I suspect that will noticeably improve things.